# AddEventListener when DOM is rendered in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I use some open library and it render some HTML DOM. I want add some event and have a small code below.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClassName");
    console.log(element.length) // Got 0
    
    element[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    //Code ....
   });
  },[])
  
  return(
  <div>
   <renderHTMLDOM /> {* Render <div className="MyClassName" />*}
  </div>
  )
```

It's mean I had a function name `renderHTMLDOM`  for render HTML.

And I want `addEventListener` in that `<div className="MyClassName"/>` I just created.

All DOM has been rendered in browser but I got `0` when `console.log(element.length)` and `addEventListener is not a function error`.

I tried condition `if(element.length) { ... }` but it not work.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Querying the DOM and attaching/mutating children elements like this is ***very*** anti-pattern in React. Use a React ref if you must, otherwise, directly attach event handlers to the specific event on the React component. I.E. `<div className="MyClassName" onMouseOver={handler} />`

Comment: Why you are doing this? any specific use case ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes, I use some library to build my web but the library not support some event.

Comment: @DrewReese I can't add `onMouseOver` because I use some library to render it.

Comment: Is `renderHTMLDOM` a function, or is it a React component? Can you share that code? I think the correct answer here is to use a ref to at least access the DOMNode of the first element your code is rendering.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, It's a React component. In my app, I use `<ReactFlow> </ReactFlow>`